# Backbone/Marionette: why shouldn't I trigger route handler on navigate?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm reading David Sulc's `A gentle introduction to Maionette`, and came across the following:

> It’s important to note that the route-handling code should get
>   fired only when a user enters the application by a URL, not each time the
>   URL changes. Put another way, once a user is within our Marionette app,
>   the route-handling shouldn’t be executed again, even when the user
>   navigates around;

What's the problem with triggering a handler on navigate?

Comment: I don't use marionette.js, but I would suspect he advices such so as to save resources. Waste the user's electricity, not your server's, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: The idea of a single page application (that is what this is talking about, correct?) is to transmit the absolute minimum amount of data on each request. I'm assuming the "route-handling code" refers to the code that directs the user to the correct place within the application when they initially visit it. After that, even if you're pushing new URLs via `window.history`, you shouldn't be "reloading" the page. You just want to grab the necessary data and update the UI appropriately.

Comment: In single page applications, executing the route handler doesn't reload the page. Usually it just replaces the old view in the current page itself.

Comment: i may be mistaken, but if i got idea right, it means that u should launch Router + Controller once on Application launch. In other words, user entered App, Router and Controller inited onces and looking after url changing to maintain the app. Also its good approach to describe router in such way to avoid manual handler triggering. All states should be declared in AppRoutes. @David Sulc, looks like you the best who can dot the "i's", could you spare us a minute and clear up this point?

Comment: I've seen this question raised before (on other sites) and I am yet to see a good explanation as to why you shouldn't trigger the route. I can certainly see situations where it would be troublesome, for instance if you create a route for deleting objects, that would be stored in the browser history and clicking back or forward onto that URL could delete a model. But that's precisely why I don't set up data changing operations as routes. I only trigger the router to display my views so that a user can directly type the URL into the browser and they'll always see the same view(s).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference IF you aren't already in your Marionette app. So say we are first getting into our Marionette app and we want it to initially route to the posts index page. Initially we can either

1. call `navigate({trigger: true)` or
2. call `navigate` (to update the URL) and then call `App.vent` to trigger the call.

Both of them will resolve in our controller's API.list function and behave exactly the same way (fetch our list of posts and then display it). So calling `trigger: true` when initially entering your app/routing to the first page is totally fine. I think David just tries to make it a practice to not do so to re-enforce the power of Marionette's pub/sub infastructure since with it you don't *need* to pass `trigger: true`.

However, let's say we're now in the list view displaying a list of posts. We've already spent the time of fetching our list of posts from the server when initially entering our app. Now we click on a post and want to view the show view of that post. The post already exists in memory so we can just do a `App.vent.trigger "post:clicked", post` to use the post already in memory to display it. If we were to instead utilize the `navigate({trigger: true})` route instead we'd end up on the same page but we would have to re-fetch the individual post instead using the one already in memory.

So the main reason is because you don't need to - triggering the page would cause a reload, re-fetch, etc. It would make your app feel slow and kind of defeat the purpose of a responsive web app/single page application.

Here's what your router should look like - you always want it setup so that you can just navigate to the page via a `App.vent` call when inside your app AND able to handle the manual browser refresh/navigating to the route directly (which is what the trigger would do, but this is the slow load that you'd kind of expect when initially fetching resources/entering the application. When in your app you want it to be the fast responsive piece that the pub/sub infrastructure affords).

```
@SampleApp.module "PostsApp", (PostsApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class PostsApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      ""            : "list"
      ":id"         : "show"

  API =
    list: ->
      new PostsApp.List.Controller

    show: (id, post) ->
      new PostsApp.Show.Controller
        id: id
        post: post

  App.vent.on "posts:list:clicked", ->
    App.navigate "/"
    API.list()

  App.vent.on "post:clicked", (post) ->
    App.navigate "/" + post.id
    API.show post.id, post


  App.addInitializer ->
    new PostsApp.Router
      controller: API
```

Then to navigate there you'd just call `App.vent.trigger "posts:list:clicked"` from wherever you want (like after clicking a "View all posts" button and bubbling the event up to the controller and active on that event).

```
@listenTo bannerView, "posts:list:button:clicked", (args) ->
    model = args.model
    App.vent.trigger "posts:list:clicked"
```

EDIT:
In the controller handling the show call to avoid the re-fetch:

```
@SampleApp.module "PostsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { post, id } = options
      post or= App.request "post:entity", id

      App.execute "when:fetched", post, =>
        @layout = @getLayoutView()

        @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @panelRegion post
          @postRegion post
          @bannerRegion post

        @show @layout
```

Comment: But how is manually calling the API.list route handler different from letting the navigate function call it?

Comment: Sure - I added a fair bit to my answer, see if that helps. Basically they will both call the API.list route if you're first entering your app - so there's no difference when initially calling them. The real benefit comes from when you already have the say posts in memory (like clicking one to see the show view). If you did the trigger route, you'd have to re-fetch that post that's already in memory

Comment: @TomHammond, I'm not seeing why triggering the route would require you to re-fetch your model from the server. If you're talking about reloading the page, then sure that's what would happen. But if you've set up a route to trigger on a particular URL then that route function can simply call whatever other function you like and either load or not load more data. I use this pattern in all of my Marionette apps to good effect, without having to fetch the model every time I trigger a route call. Unless I'm missing something obvious here, it seems like two ways of doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I second @Simon's comment. The route handler shouldn't trigger a page refresh, it usually just creates a new view and updates the dom. As for refetching, the entity module wouldn't have to fetch a model/collection from the server if it's fetched it previously. Given these two points, I still don't see what the disadvantage of triggering a route is.

Comment: The only case I can think of is when the route handler creates a layout with multiple views. In that case, it'd be better to just call the controller of the view(s) that need to be updated, so the remaining views of the layout don't have to be recreated and reinserted into the dom.

Comment: I'm probably just awful at explaining. I agree the API.list route handler wouldn't trigger the re-fetch unless it's triggered by navigate({trigger: true}). In that case it's basically the same as manually clicking the refresh button in the browser and everything would be refreshed.

Comment: @Simon would you mind editing your question with an example of how you're thinking you'd do it? I think I'm following but just want to be sure :).

Comment: @TomHammond Perhaps one of my answers to another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323999/maintain-a-stack-of-marionette-itemviews-within-a-marionette-layout/19335210#19335210) will show you what I mean. Obviously this is a very basic and contrived example but it does the job. Also, our examples are both a bit different, but let me know if it's not making sense.

Comment: @TomHammond, something that isn't clear in the example I provided is that I only trigger the router to show new views/layouts etc, such as going between a show/list view as in your example. If there is DOM manipulation within a view then that is handled in the view itself using the `events` hash and doesn't trigger a route update. Data manipulation such as POST/PUT/DELETE type actions also don't update the route which could be very bad when clicking back/forward.